# Issues with input from user

Tags: java, user-input

I have an input from user of the following form:

```
1234 abc def gfh
..
8789327 kjwd jwdn
stop
```

now if i use Scanner and in turn use

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String t=sc.nextLine();
while(!t.equals("stop"))
{
    int i=sc.nextInt();
    int str=sc.nextLine();
    t=sc.nextLine();
}
```

Is there some way by which i may get 
  i=1234
  str="abc def gfh"
...
and so on...and stop when the user enters a stop

I want to accept the numerical values and strings separately...without using regex.
Also I want to stop taking input with keyword "stop".

Comment: Do you want to read each tokens separately?

Comment: I don't believe this will compile, will it ? int str=  sc.nextLine(); ?

Comment: Even if it would compile, it would be an endless loop, or a loop that would be skipped completely

Comment: post your complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Your new question is very different from the previous one. And @chaitanya10 I don't think we'll need the stacktrace.

Comment: ya..i gave a +1 to the first answer..and admitted that I have modified my question

Comment: You are not showing us the code which causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How can we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are doing nothing with the accepted input, just ignoring it to take next input.

Second, `scanner.nextLine()` returns you the next line read which is String. To get the tokens separately, you would need to split the `string` read to get them.

Third, you should check in your while, whether you have next input or not using [`scanner#hasNextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29), if its equal to `true`, then only you should read your input in your while loop.

If you want to read each token separately, you should better use [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method, which returns the next token read.

Also, you want to read `integers` and `strings`, so you also need to test, whether you are having an integer. You would need to use [`Scanner#hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method for that.

Ok, since you want to read `integer` and `string` separately on each line.

**Here's what you can try: -**

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {  // Check whether you have nextLine to read

    String str = scanner.nextLine(); // Read the nextLine

    if (str.equals("stop")) {  // If line is "stop" break
        break;
    }

    String[] tokens = str.split(" ", 1);  // Split your string with limit 1
                                          // This will give you 2 length array

    int firstValue = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);  // Get 1st integer value
    String secondString = tokens[1];  // Get next string after integer value
}
```

Comment: First point...the code with which i got to do something with the accepted input is long...therefore not posted here...however I hope my intent is clear..anyways thanks for helping

Comment: Second point...exactly...however for example i want to accept i=1234, str="abc def gfh"..therefore splitting on a space does not help me

Comment: @JannatArora. You are using wrong methods to do what you want to do. You should check the documentation link that I posted and read about the methods to know what each of them do.

Comment: @JannatArora. Are you having only the first value as `int`?

Comment: @JannatArora. You can use `split` with 2nd parameter, which tells how many split you want. Give that parameter as `1` which will split your input string only once.

Comment: @JannatArora. See [`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method, where 2nd parameter is the number of split. So, if you do: - `str.split(" ", 1);` it will only split once.

Comment: @JannatArora. Updated post. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `t` so the while condition will be always true unless the first line of your file is `stop`.

Comment: Ya true +1 to u...i hav modified the question...pls help me with it.

Comment: Like this instead t only gets odd lines (and str only the even lines) and you are also redefining t.

Comment: ya exactly...this is what i dont want...therefore the question... :)

Comment: Why str is an int? Why not just using t? You can remove the str statement.

Comment: ya...but by just using t...i got to split it on space...but there are  a lot os spaces here

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String t=sc.nextLine();
while(!t.equals("stop"))
{
    int i=sc.nextInt();
    int str=sc.nextLine();
    t=sc.nextLine();
}
```

First of all `int str=sc.nextLine();` is wrong as `nextLine()` returns string. According to me, what you can do is:

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String t=sc.nextLine();
    int i;
    String str="";
    while(!t.equals("stop"))
    {
        int index=t.indexOf(" ");
        if(index==-1)
           System.out.println("error");
        else{
               i=Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0,index));
               str=t.substring(index+1);
        }
        t=sc.nextLine();
    }
```

I hope it helps.